# opencv 3.0, about using Ptr<SURF> ( surf algorithm)

Tags: opencv

this code is example about `surf algorithm`.
but when I execute this code, I have a error message.

> error : error LNK2019: "public: static struct cv::Ptr __cdecl
>   cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double,int,int,bool,bool)"
>   (?create@SURF@xfeatures2d@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VSURF@xfeatures2d@cv@@@3@NHH_N0@Z)

why I have this error? I have to use surf algorithm. 
what is the solution about this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

void readme();

int main()
{
  Mat img_1 = imread( "a.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
  Mat img_2 = imread( "b.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

  if( !img_1.data || !img_2.data )
  { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

  //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
  int minHessian = 400;

  Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( minHessian );

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

  detector->detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
  detector->detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

  //-- Draw keypoints
  Mat img_keypoints_1; Mat img_keypoints_2;

  drawKeypoints( img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar::all(-1),     DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
  drawKeypoints( img_2, keypoints_2, img_keypoints_2, Scalar::all(-1),     DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );

  //-- Show detected (drawn) keypoints
  imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1 );
  imshow("Keypoints 2", img_keypoints_2 );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
  }

  /** @function readme */
  void readme()
      { std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_detector <img1> <img2>" << std::endl; }
```

Comment: I want to use this code in visual studio. not linux !

Comment: Have you linked to opencv_xfeatures2d30X(d).lib?

Comment: I just download from github. but I don't add library because I don't know how do it add